# Angular2 attach ngFor rendered HTML element to the data

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have an array of objects that I want to iterate over using Angular's *ngFor.

After the items are rendered, I want to set a new property on the objects (called nativeElement) that references the HTML node rendering that object.

The following code illustrates the goal, but obviously doesnt work.

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of arrayOfObjs"
     [ngInit]="obj.nativeElement = thisDivNode">

</div>
```

How can I set the element reference on the obj in the cleanest way?

Comment: which version of angular you are using beta or stable

Comment: I'm using stable/final

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a directive and pass the item to it, and let the directive assign the element to the item

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[addElement]'
})
class AddElementDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('addElement') obj: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obj.nativeElement = this.el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.obj.nativeElement = null;
  }
}
```

Then just use it like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" [addElement]="item">
</div>
```

Personally I think this is cleaner than any markup acrobatics you can come up with.

Comment: I like this. It would be even better if you could ask ngFor to give the current "item" without passing it in an attribute. Something like <my-element *ngFor="let item of data"></my-element> and letting the component take care of that internally automatically. Is that possible?

Comment: Also, is ngOnDestroy truly necessary for this? Can you explain why this would cause a memory leak? If the item was removed from the collection, how can you be sure it won't be properly clean it up ?